# pass list in to sklearn - accuracy_score for scoring

Tags: python, scikit-learn

my demo is here-:

```
a=[1.47, 4.13, -2.51, 2.47, 5.45, 4.3, 8.97, -0.19, 11.79]             

b=[1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

f=accuracy_score(a, b)

print(f)
```

this is error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous targets`

is there any way to solve this error , because I don't have same type of data  (here I have (list of Int and list of Float))

Comment: Sklearn.metrices is only available for classification models. Your input contains continuous values which can't be class labels .
If you want to calculate accuracy for regression models. Use methods like RMSE, MAPE, APE, R2 etc. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy score is only for classification problems. And your input contains continuous values, not label! For regression problems you can use: R2 Score, MSE (Mean Squared Error), RMSE (Root Mean Squared Error).

See the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) for info on the various metrics.